# Is it possible to add links to images in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't change the html, so is it possible to do something like (a href="") in css?

I saw that I can use jQuery to do it, but there aren't any specific classes for each slide, just a general class:

```html
<div class="slick-slider draggable">
    <div class="slick-slider">
        <figure class="slick-slide-inner"><img class="slick-slide-image" alt="PLANOS"></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slider">...</div>
    <div class="slick-slider">...</div>
    <div class="slick-slider">...</div>
    <div class="slick-slider">...</div>
    <div class="slick-slider">...</div>
    <div class="slick-slider">...</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```css
figure.slick-slide-inner[alt="PLANOS"]{
    /*and command to add link*/
}
```

Comment: It is not the same problem, I think.

Comment: It looks to be the exact same problem to me. How does your problem differ?

Comment: javascript and jQuery can do this for sure. I don't think css can.

Comment: css is a styling language: it can't alter the structure of the page

Comment: In that post the porpuse is to add a link to a image provided by css. My problem is the opposite I think, I have the image in the html, and wanted to know if is possible to add the link to another page trough css, since I can't change the html.

Comment: @Chimelin Please describe clearly what you want to achieve. What is the source data and what is your desired end result? It's kinda unclear. From you commend i suspect you like to scrape (A part of) the html from a page you don't have access too and use this on another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as everyone is saying you cannot do this with pure css.

As you have tagged jquery on this question I suppose you just want to get a solution.

You can do it with something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".slick-slide-image[alt='PLANOS']").wrap('<a href="https://www.example.com/"></a>');
});
```

Although, on the list of mad ideas that I've seen today, selecting things by their `alt` tag is at the top.

Comment: I'm a beginner, didn't even know I could use alt in css, but I don't see any other way of selecting them. Thank you, it was something like this that worked.

Comment: @Chimelin normally you would give your elements an unique ID which you can use. Because the alt text is just a hardcoded message which can contain random information and this text is optional and normally not used in any other way then explaining an image to blind people. Because the alt text of an image is used for text to speech.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is only to tell html how it should display. Except `content` you can not modify html at all using CSS.

I suggest you to write script in JQuery. If you know order of images and know links for them and order will not change you can always modify it.

Also if you know `src` value for images and its corresponding link, you can use JQuery again to redirect user based on that.

Hope it helps :)